# Stacking two ContainerViews?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, segue, uicontainerview

I have an `UIViewController` with its `TableView` view.
For the `TableView` header, I need to show 2 separate `views`, based on some flags.
I have 2 `ContainerViews`, each with its own `embedding`, two separate `UIViewControllers`. I was trying to show/hide the `ContainerViews`'s `view`, based on the above mentioned flags.
The problem is that, the embedded views are not showing up like I expect them to. Here is my code:

```
//main `UIViewController` code; simplified
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"header_1"]) {
        if(_shouldShowH1){
          self.headerViewController = (HeaderViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
          [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.headerViewController.view];
        }
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"header_2"]){
        if(_shouldShowH2){
          self.headerViewController2 = (HeaderViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
          [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.headerViewController2.view];
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that, even if I call `bringSubviewToFront:`, I don't see the actual View. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved my issue following this post http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers with one minor modification: I don't need to swap the views, so I removed the functionality.
I decide beforehand which segue needs to be performed, so the decision branching is also removed.